# Arena Daemon multiplayer integration (iOS + Android)

Tags: ios, cross-platform, multiplayer

I'm trying to use **arenadaemon sdk** ([**LINK**](http://www.arenadaemon.com)) to build a multi-player game for **iOS**. I successfully retrieve the tables list and also the registration goes fine, but I can not understand when a match starts.

How can I hook that event?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a match with 2 or more players, 
you need each player register to the same table.

**Scenario**

The table is full(no seats left) the match automatically starts and each player receive the event (for iOS)

```
iOS : - (void) arenaPlay:(BDArenaPlayConnector*)connector matchDidStart:(BDArenaMatchData*)matchData;
```

Android :

```
public void arenaPlayMatchDidStart(BDArenaPlayConnector connector, BDArenaMatchData matchInfo)
```

once a match starts, you can exchange messages between player calling the methods you can find under ‘Managing matches’ paragraph of the documentation

http://arenadaemon.com/references/detail/33

http://arenadaemon.com/references/detail/8